# Continuous infinitve

Tags: sentence-structure

Can someone explain when it is natural to use the continuous infintive. Let me explain we can all agree that saying something like " What were you doing at 5 pm. yesterday" is perfectly correct and natural both when it comes to grammar and how it sounds to native speakers. Another example " What were you doing in October" here it is correct according to grammar structers but it is not really natural to say something like thatt if we don not mean some specfic time during October. To conclusion, My question is: please tell me or explain what it the brodast time frame which still goess well with the continuous infintive without us thinking about some particular time during that time frame unlike "What were you doing in October"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by continuous infinitival. There's no infinitive in your example. The time frame is entirely dependent on context. It's perfectly natural to say "What were you doing in October?" when discussing things that someone did in, say, the autumnal months. Semantically, there's no real difference between "what were you doing?" and "what did you do"".

Comment: You think that for example what did you do yesterday and what were you doing yesterday mean the same thing and are interchangeable?

Comment: It is completely and perfectly 'natural' to say 'what were you doing in October?'. I, personally, was giving up smoking.

Comment: My teacher says it's wrong that only simple is correct for such long times. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: They say for example when someone asks me how long did you worl there I'm not allowed to say using continuois I was working there for 4  years but in simple

Comment: Your examples are only 'perfectly correct' if you add a question mark!

Comment: But some people told here on this site that it is wrong and know you say there is really no difference. Why is that?

Comment: "Sorry I could not help you in October. I was busy." "Really? What were you doing in October?" "I was working there for 4 years, and suddenly my fulltime job was finding another job all October!"

Comment: But we wouldn't say "When I was little I was going to school" why is that?

Comment: I think there's no limit on how broad the span can be. "During the millions of years in which the Earth was changing from a ball of molten rock into a habitable planet, *what was happening* on Mars?" Please edit to cite whatever source gave you this impression, and then answers can focus on any potential misunderstanding.

Comment: @trainbee282 I suggest you pipe down and give the OP, Adam, time to respond to the comments..

Comment: @Andy Boner my teachers and some people said that for example " When I was little I was going to school or I was working there for 2 years or What were you doing yesterday( if we don't thinl about some specific poin like when I called) are all wrong. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @trainbee282 I'm confused, are you actually a second account belonging to Adam? If so, try to only use one account. If not, please don't use comment sections for discussion. Use the chat channel, or contribute an answer if you have one, or wait for this one to get an answer (which shouldn't happen until it's edited to include the advice Adam heard, since right now the only answer we can give is "you're wrong," which isn't very helpful). Some of your examples are different cases than what's being discussed here.

Comment: @Andy Boner. Can we chat together?

Comment: @trainbee282 Sure; https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow